# TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to develop a basic reinforcement model because I am trying to gain exposure to the industry. I am currently trying to train a cart or something so that a pole stays upright on it. Here is my code so far.

```
import gym 
import random 

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions = env.action_space.n

#Building Random Enviroment
episodes = 10 
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    state = env.reset() 
    done = False 
    score = 0 
    
    while not done: 
        env.render()
        action = random.choice([0,1])
        n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward 
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))

#Create the Model 
import numpy 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten 
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam 

def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, states)))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model

model = build_model(states, actions)

#Build Agent 
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy 
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy() 
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
      2 dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
      3 dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)

Cell In[11], line 4, in build_agent(model, actions)
      2 policy = BoltzmannQPolicy() 
      3 memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
----> 4 dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=actions, target_model_update=1e-2)
      5 return dqn

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py:108, in DQNAgent.__init__(self, model, policy, test_policy, enable_double_dqn, enable_dueling_network, dueling_type, *args, **kwargs)
    105 super(DQNAgent, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    107 # Validate (important) input.
--> 108 if hasattr(model.output, '__len__') and len(model.output) > 1:
    109     raise ValueError('Model "{}" has more than one output. DQN expects a model that has a single output.'.format(model))
    110 if model.output._keras_shape != (None, self.nb_actions):

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\keras_tensor.py:244, in KerasTensor.__len__(self)
    243 def __len__(self):
--> 244     raise TypeError(
    245         "Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not "
    246         "implement `__len__`. You may be "
    247         "trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs "
    248         "to a TF API that does not register dispatching, "
    249         "preventing Keras from automatically "
    250         "converting the API call to a lambda layer "
    251         "in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised "
    252         "if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly."
    253     )

TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly.
```

Please let me know what I can do to fix this.

Thank you in advance,

I have tried to reinstall different python libraries through pip, and have tried looking for help through stack overflow. None of these worked and I still have this problem.